# C# draw curve and polygon with mouse events

Tags: c#, drawing, gdi+

I am a beginner in C#, so be gentle.

In C#, I want draw curves and polygons like in Paint; where you hold the left mouse button to draw. Can you give some advice or code on how to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the beginning, try just tracing the mouse with `Graphics.LineTo()` - then start to play with mouse down and up events, then go from there.  There is much to explore in the graphics area, and it should be lots of fun!

As for the array:

```
List<Point> points=new List<Point>();
```

later, on mouse move:

```
points.Add(new Point(mouse.X,mouse.Y));
```

and much later, if you need real point array

```
Point[] pa=points.ToArray();
```

Comment: what`s with mouse new points putting in array, how should it look like in code ? i mean this kind of stuff  pp[0] = new Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);

Comment: for starters ignore the array, just draw them with LineTo

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the mouse down, move and mouse up events while persisting some data which is then drawn on the Paint event of whatever control you are painting into.

Take a look at this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/drawingshape.aspx) for a good example of what you need to do.

For connecting points with a curve you should look at [this article for drawing Bezier curves](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/BezirCurves.aspx) from a set of points. Here's another one [that does spline interpolation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SplineInterpolation.aspx).

Comment: i`m painting in Paint event, actually i need to know how to connect those little points, as you know curve is made from many points :)

Comment: Added a link for drawing Bezier curves into my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The CodeProject article referenced by Paul Sasik is an excellent starting point.  For drawing curved lines, you might want to try using `Graphics.DrawBezier(...)`, which takes an array of points as a parameter, and renders a curved line through the points.  This will have some complexity issues, though, as you need to decide how many consecutive points to use for each segment, and how to handle the running overlaps.

Comment: ok, i have code, that draws curve when i click mouse left/right button un connects those points, but how to make that drawing is when i click and hold mouse button, like in paint ? i made code, but it`s very long, how can i paste it in here ? maybe can somebody correct it ?